# Use german accounts for gnucash

Tags: gnucash

am new to gnucash and I need a special set of accounts which are common in Germany. They are called SKR03 (i am not an account)

If I understand the documentation right I need to set the language to de_DE. If I do it and start gnucash nothing happens. Everything stays in English and I can not see the SKR03.

What am I doing wrong? I am using MacOSx and my system language is English.